# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): The method "neighbors" already exists

Tags: angular, sigma.js

I'm new in sigma.js, I'm using sigma.js with angular 7, when I add neighbors method into a graph is looking good. Also, first time graph looking good but when I change route and again call graph page, I got an error like ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): The method "neighbors" already exists.

my code like

```js
sigma.classes.graph.addMethod("neighbors", function(nodeId) {
      var k,
        neighbors = {},
        index = this.allNeighborsIndex[nodeId] || {};

      for (k in index) neighbors[k] = this.nodesIndex[k];

      return neighbors;
    });

    this.s = new sigma({
      graph: this.graph,
      renderer: {
        container: document.getElementById("sigma-container"),
        type: "canvas"
      },
      settings: {
        defaultEdgeType: "line",
        defaultNodeColor: "#aaabaa",
        autoRescale: ["nodePosition", "nodeSize"],
        labelThreshold: 0,
        adjustSizes: true,
        enableEdgeHovering: true,
        edgeHoverColor: "#393a3c",
        defaultEdgeHoverColor: "#393a3c",
        edgeHoverExtremities: true
      }
    });

    this.s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
      n.originalColor = n.color;
    });
    this.s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
      e.originalColor = e.color;
    });

    this.s.bind("overNode", e => {
      this.createSelectTeamMemberGraph(e);
    });
  }

  public createSelectTeamMemberGraph(user) {
    let e = user;
    var nodeId = user.userId || e.data.node.id,
      toKeep = this.s.graph.neighbors(nodeId);
    toKeep[nodeId] = e || e.data.node;

    this.s.graph.nodes().forEach(function(n) {
      if (toKeep[n.id]) n.color = n.originalColor;
      else n.color = "#aaaaab";
    });

    this.s.graph.edges().forEach(function(e) {
      if (toKeep[e.source] && toKeep[e.target]) e.color = e.originalColor;
      else e.color = "#aaaaab";
    });
    this.s.refresh();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error arises since sigma js has already loaded once and it had added the method called 'neighbor'. If this method is again added to the sigma js configuration it will show this error "Method already exists".

The workaround is to call the below part of the code only once:

```
sigma.classes.graph.addMethod("neighbors", function(nodeId) {
      var k,
        neighbors = {},
        index = this.allNeighborsIndex[nodeId] || {};

      for (k in index) neighbors[k] = this.nodesIndex[k];

      return neighbors;
    });
```

This can be done by writing this part of code in a separate js file which is called only once.